# No list items in last created navbar button. Using my own function

Tags: jquery, navbar, listitem

I am not getting any options (list items) or getting and empty option in my third navbar created using my own function. Funny enough it works in edge if I include the alert in the navBar function also it will create a navBar with all options etc if I am going to just produce an array variable and manually insert values into this array without populating this array through my written function. Please have a look at the code below.

```
var tims = [];
//populates the array with teams
function getTeams(tims) {
    $.getJSON("teams.json").done(function(data) {
        var tim1 = data.sports_content.teams;
        for (var i in tim1.team) {
            if (tim1.team[i].is_nba_team == true) {
                tims.push(tim1.team[i].city + ' ' + tim1.team[i].team_nickname);
            }
        }
    })
    return tims;
}

//function used to create a navbar
function navBar(id, header, options, cssParams, cssRed) {
    var content = "<ul class= 'dropdown-menu ";
    var css = "";
    var css1 = "";
    //setting up css for a navbar
    for (var j in cssParams) {
        css += cssParams[j] + " ";
    }
    content += css + "' >";

    //creating list of css elements for navbar placement
    for (var z = 0; z < cssParams.length - cssRed; z++) {
        css1 += cssParams[z] + " ";

    }
    //alert(css1); 
    //creating list elements for a navbar
    for (var i in options) {

        content += "<li><a id ='" + id + i + "' href='#'>" + options[i] + "</a></li>";
    }
    content += "</ul>";
    $('#nBar').append("<div class='btn-group '> <button id = '" + id + "' type='button' class='" + css1 + " btn btn-primary btn-lg dropdown-toggle ' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>" + header + "<span class='caret'></span></button>" + content + "</div>");
    //alert(content);
}

//creating three navbars , the third one appears to be empty
    var tims = new Array();
    tims = getTeams(tims);
navBar("func", "func", ["news", "roster", "stadium", "switch the team"], ["navMv", "options1", "col1"], 2);
navBar("nba", "Nba", ["top 10 last night", "commisioner", "info"], ["navMv", "next", "options1", "col1"], 2);
navBar("team", "team", tims, ["navMv", "next1", "options1", "col1"], 2);
```

If I alert `tims[any_element]` I will get the right pop up. Thought it was worth mentioning.
For instance this is going to give me the name of the first team if I am going to press the first list item of a func navBar but the team navbar list will be empty:

```
        $('#main').ready(function(){
                var tims = new Array();
                tims = getTeams(tims);
                navBar("func","func",["news","roster","stadium","switch the team"],["navMv","options1","col1"],2);
                navBar("nba","Nba",["top 10 last night","commisioner","info"],["navMv","next","options1","col1"],2);
                navBar("team","team",tims,["navMv","next1","options1","col1"],2);

                $("#func0").click(function(event){
                    alert(tims[0]);
                     event.preventDefault;
                })

           });
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you put that alert for tims? I would say your tims is still an empty array. In your function getTeams you return the changed variable, but that is not assigned. You need to write

```
tims = getTeams(tims);
```

Comment: I have updated my code now using what you have suggested Seb and thank you for that. Altough I am still getting the same problem for some reason. If I enclose the creation of that single navBar element in lets say click event function on any object in my website , I am going to get this navBar created with all of the names of teams but can not access through an id for some reason. The only way it works is when I am adding alert(content) (which seems to run twice every time the page is loaded) at the end of the navBar function and than I can access all itesm by their id's. Any idea why?